# With fractional shares available why do we still have stock splits?

Tags: stocks, stock-split, fractional-shares

I understand how before you would need to do a stock split when the company value surges since it is not easy for a "poor" diversified investor to have a $2000 stock in his portfolio, but these days you can buy a [fraction of a share](https://robinhood.com/us/en/support/articles/fractional-shares/), so I see no point in stock splits.

But recently AAPL announced a stock split and its [market capitalization went up](https://www.forbes.com/sites/greatspeculations/2020/08/21/tesla--apple-surge-with-stock-split-announcement-are-amazon-chipotle--google-next/).

Comment: Who works with fractions of shares? The company you are buying or your broker?

Comment: Fractional shares are an "illusion" created by some stock brokers. Fractional shares are possible when the shares are held in street name. In the company's shareholder register, there are no owners with fractional shares.